# How to Get Subscriptions from "My Reports" Folders in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report on SSRS subscriptions (query code below).  The problem is that it is not capturing subscriptions when developers are sending subscriptions for reports out of their own folders.  Is there any way I can capture "My Reports" subscriptions?

```
    SELECT
       c.Name as [ReportName]
      ,su.Description as [SubscriptionDesc]
      ,c.Path as [ReportPath]
      ,coalesce(NULLIF(pc.Path,''),'/') as [ReportFolder]
      ,su.EventType as [SubscriptionType]
      ,replace(su.DeliveryExtension,'Report Server ', '') as [DeliveryExtension]
      ,su.LastRunTime
      ,su.LastStatus
      ,su.SubscriptionID as [SubscriptionID]
    FROM Subscriptions su
     left JOIN Catalog c
    ON su.Report_OID = c.ItemID
      left join Catalog pc on c.ParentID=pc.ItemID
    ORDER BY ReportPath, ReportName
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These subscriptions should still be caught in the execution log, you could try this:

```
select *
from dbo.ExecutionLog el 
left join dbo.Subscriptions s on s.Report_OID = el.ReportID
where s.SubscriptionID is null
order by 1 desc
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will look at the results and confirm as answer once I have had a chance to validate.  Not sure about this line, though:`where s.SubscriptionID is null`

Comment: It must be NULL or it would appear in your own query as you are getting all subscriptions from dbo.subscriptions and you say it's not there.  Mine will show all reports executed that are not stored in dbo.subscriptions.  Perhaps we have crossed wires.

Comment: In the end I just lifted the restriction to be able to see everything.  To my (pleasant!) surprise, I found that there are actually no subscriptions running from personal folders.  This was very helpful. Thank you!